# Which is the best way to set a bit & why?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit, bitmask

If I had to set 4th bit,

Which is the best way

Method 1:
    a |= (1 << 3)

Method 2:
    a |= 8

Please elaborate the difference.

Comment: There is no difference at execution time. Any compiler should constant-fold `1 << 3` into `8`. At *reading* time the difference is that `1 << 3` makes it clear that you're setting the third bit.

Answer (score 2):

These two are equivalent.

Using `1 << 3` is more clear to the reader which bit you want to set.  And because this expression is a compile-time constant, compilers will typically calculate the value at compile time so there is no run-time overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, both of these do the same thing. Let me focus on the part which is different:

- (1 << 3) take the number 1 (binary: 0000 0001) and shift it 3 spots to the left (binary: 0000 1000)
- 8 take the number 8 (binary: 0000 1000)

As you can see, the result is the same binary number: 0000 1000

If I have to choose between these 2, I'd pick the shift, as this is more obvious that you want a bit. However, personally, I would pick a third variant when creating these numbers: `0b0000'1000`

The `0b` stands for binary literal, available since C++14 and the `'` is a digit separator (also C++14), which is similar to the spaces I used earlier.

However, to be fair, I think you are using the wrong tool for the job assuming `a` is an integer. [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is created to do these kind of bit manipulations. (Even available in C++98)

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto a = std::bitset<8>{};
    a.set(3 /*zero based indexing*/);
    std::cout << a.to_string() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program: `00001000`

[Code at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/pJhpaW)

As you can see, you can very easy set bits with the method `set` as if it was any other container. See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) for more things you can do.